# OpenCL - save region of an image

Tags: opencl

I am using OpenCL C 1.2 and in order to read back an image on the host, I use this code:

```
// Read the output buffer back to the Host
char *buffer = malloc((width * height)*sizeof(char*)*4); //new char 
[width * height * 4];
size_t origin[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
size_t region[3] = { width, height, 1};
errNum = clEnqueueReadImage(commandQueue, imageObjects[1], CL_TRUE,
                            origin, region, 0, 0, buffer,
                            0, NULL, NULL);
```

How can I read only a specific region of the image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would set `origin` and `region` that described the sub-image that you want to read. Only that sub-region of the image will be coped out into host memory.